# Kohana 3.2 Validate More Than One Model

Tags: php, validation, orm, kohana

I've been searching Google, but I have not found any examples on how to validate more than one model with Kohana 3.2.

```
try 
{
     $one = ORM::factory('one'); 
     $one->values($this->request->post());
     $one->check();
     $two = ORM::factory('two'); 
     $two->values($this->request->post());
     $two->check();
} 
catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
     $errors = $e->errors('models'); 
}
```

If "one" has any errors, "two" is never checked.

Comment: And whats the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regular behaviour using `try catch`. Rewriting the code like the following should do it

```
$errors = array();
try
{
    $one = ORM::factory('one')->values($this->request->post());
    $one->check();
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    $errors = array_merge($errors, $e->errors('models'));
}
try
{
    $two = ORM::factory('two')->values($this->request->post());
    $two->check();
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    $errors = array_merge($errors, $e->errors('models'));
}
```